What linux chat app can I use to send an otr/omemo message non-interactively
I currently use profanity-im to manually paste and send short outputs of my work to my superior through a local intranet's xmpp (ejabberd) chat system.
General objective: I want to automate a few steps such that I can non-interactively send such messages, such as triggering the sending via vim or ranger or any other component in my workflow. This is the part I can handle myself.
Problem: The problem lies with the transmission of the message. As profanity-im does not have a commandline facility to accomplish the transmission, I've attempted using commandline interface of other chat clients like pidgin or gajim. I found weechat difficult to use as I cannot make it work and its otr dependencies can no longer be found.
In other words, I need an app that I can script like this or something similar:
chat-app-command send "applicant just submitted resume" -from <sender@server> -to <receiver@server> --otr-key <otrfile>

Any streetsign to point me in the right direction will be highly appreciated.
[UPDATE] I realize one-on-one chat (as opposed to MUC) can use omemo. Further research is being undertaken as omemo may be more friendly regarding my objective.
